# Calculate the radius of an ellipse using Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

If I have the height and width of an ellipse and the angle from the center.
How can I calculate the radius of the ellipse from that angle?

I don't understand the maths enough to understand how to make this work in Javascript

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432902/how-to-get-the-radius-of-an-ellipse-at-a-specific-angle-by-knowing-its-semi-majo

Comment: Thanks @AllanWind I saw that but had no idea how to convert into Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works:

```
let s = Math.sin(angle)
let c = Math.cos(angle)
let r = (a*b)/Math.sqrt(a*a*s*s+b*b*c*c)
```

where `a` is the horizontal axis, `b` is the vertical axis, and `angle` is the, well, angle.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Take -

a = width/2

b = height/2

and theta as the angle measured from the horizontal axis.

```
x = a*a*Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(theta);
y = b*b*Math.cos(theta)*Math.cos(theta);
r = (a*b)/Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

for more information [look at this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432902/how-to-get-the-radius-of-an-ellipse-at-a-specific-angle-by-knowing-its-semi-majo)

Hope this helps.